# How to determine which Process Template in VS2010 to use?

Tags: .net, tfs, tfs-process-template

I am curious as to which Process Template in Visual Studio's Team Foundation Server people tend to use and why.

I am a Solo Developer in a .Net shop that makes in-house apps only.  I make all kinds of applications for our company.  Many are critical and used daily by a majority of our 300 employee's.  These app's will be around for awhile and in constant maintenance.

Which process would work better for my situation? What do I need to understand to make this decision myself?  Which process would work the best for constantly evolving/changing applications.

As an example of what I mean; I just took our Core App, which was a Web App and re-wrote it as a Sometimes Connected WinForm app to allow our Nurses remote use of the program.

The 2 included in VS Team Server 2010 are `MSF for Agile Software Development` & `MSF for CMMI Process Improvement`.

For reference see here --> [Team System Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/aa718801.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSF Agile is the way to go for you.  You are a solo developer, and agile will allow you to capture your backlog of work to complete and rank and prioritize it easily without all the overhead of the CMMI process.

Answer (score 1):

Don't look for other. Read the process guidelines carefully and choose the one that best fits YOUR! needs. You can start here:

[Choosing a Process Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400752(VS.100).aspx)